# Как сделать логирование в Junit после assert();?

Tags: java, логирование, junit

Как сделать логирование в Junit, если тест НЕ прошел. Грубо говоря, как сделать, чтобы выполнился код после `assertTrue(res);`

Answer (score 2):

Никак. На то он и assert. Если надо что-то сделать, то делайте проверку руками типа

```
assertTrue("my message tra-la-la", res);
```

Или

```
if (!res) {
    // build message
    fail(message ...);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1. Самое простое, при запуске консольного раннера тестов перенаправить вывод в файл.
2. Если нужно что-то более сложное, то нужно будет переопределить класс [Runner](http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runner/Runner.html) и реализовать своб логику обработки событий, возникающих при прогоне тестов.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы не использовать обыкновенный try..catch?

Привожу пример

```
AssertionError assertionError = null;

try{
  //test code here
}catch(AssertionError aEr){
  assertionError = aEr;
}finally{
  if(assertionError == null){
    // log success
  }else{
    // log fail
    throw assertionError;
  }
}
```

Переопределить Runner - тоже вариант, только по сути он будет делать абсолютно то же самое. Имеет смысл так делать, если это не единичный случай: можно будет использовать и для других тестов.